# SaaS implementation with Micro-services

Tags: microservices

I'm trying to build a web-based SaaS solution in ASP.NET Core 2.0, with the help of micro-services architecture, token based authentication and service will be hosted on Docker. Each client has its own users, product and other details with multiple databases with shared schema. Each micro-service has its own database (Schema-per-service).

I hit a roadblock where I need to locate logged in user’s database credentials (connection string), so that database connection will be passed dynamically to respective micro-service to fetch data from respective client database?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have some sort of microservice to handle client authentication into his SaaS account and generate a token to consume the SaaS microservices (like a "private key") correct?
It's the perfect case for microservices architecture:

1. Create a microservice that domains resources about the client's environment configuration
2. This microservice receives requests with the client's private key
3. Then requests the authentication service to validate the passed private key
4. Get the response of the authentication service and some sort of client's unique key
5. Responds with the environment configuration corresponding to that client's unique key (or 404 if the  auth token doesn't match with any client)

Now having this microservice (I'll call "environment microservice"), any other microservice of your SaaS just needs request the environment microservice to get  client's configurations (database connection string, storage system and etc). From this point, you can implement some caching policy at each service to keep the private keys mapping to a set of configurations (and persistent database connections if your model permits). Just ensure that this cache has an interval to validate the tokens and configurations against the environment microservice.

Comment: Thanks Vicor for your reply, client authentication is handle in Identity microservice (where it checks user’s identity and sends auth token and not passing private key). It looks like, I need to add some sort of client's unique key in the token itself and call an environment microservice to get client's configurations (database connection string etc.).

Comment: Only one thing that worries me, I need to access token in each microservices’s RESTful methods so that appropriate client’s connection string can be fetch and establish database connection, as I cannot access token in  controller’s constructor. If the Microservice has to serve multiple tenants (say 50) it will need 50 different connection strings and that many number of connection pools. Will this impact request performance?

Comment: To avoid flooding your Identity microservice with requests, you can keep the mapping of the token to connection string cached (in memory or temporary file) at each microservice that needs that configuration. So, on the first request the microservice will request the Identity microservice for the connection string, in the next requests microservice can see if the cache contains that token. You also can implement a cache refresh policy (after x seconds for example).

Comment: Thanks Vicor, will try to incorporate the mapping of the token to connection string cache.